# TypeError: data.matchAll is not a function discord.js 13.6.0

Tags: node.js, discord.js

This is my code

```
            if (data.guild.plugins.partnerCounting.enabled) {
                if (message.channel.id === data.guild.plugins.partnerCounting.channel) {
                    if (/(discord\.(gg|io|me|li)\/.+|discordapp\.com\/invite\/.+)/i.test(message.content)) {

                        const Messages = require("discord-messages"); // messagecountertest
                        const messagesSchema = require("../base/Messages")
                        let UserDataPartner = await messagesSchema.findOne({
                            userID: message.author.id,
                            guildID: message.guild.id
                        })
                        if (!UserDataPartner) {
                            Messages.createUser(message.author.id, message.guild.id) 
                        }

                        const inviteLink = await message.content.match(new RegExp(`discord\.(gg|io|me|li)\/.+|discordapp\.com\/invite\.+`))
                        setTimeout(async () => {
                         // in this 
                ---------> await client.fetchInvite(inviteLink) <---------
                                .then(async (invite) => {

                                    if (data.guild.plugins.partnerCounting.ignored.includes(invite.guild.id)) {
                                        return message.error("f. utility/partnercount:IGNORED_GUILD")

                                    } else {

                                        await Messages.appendMessage(message.author.id, message.guild.id, 1);

                                        const user = await Messages.fetch(message.author.id, message.guild.id);

                                        setTimeout(async () => {
                                            const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                                                .setAuthor({ name: `${message.author.tag} | ${message.author.id}`, iconURL: message.author.displayAvatarURL({ size: 512, dynamic: true, format: 'png' }) }).setDescription(message.translate("f. utility/partnercount:SETDESCRIPTION", {
                                                    guild: invite.guild.name,
                                                    amount: user.data.messages
                                                }))
                                                .setFooter({ text: message.translate("f. utility/partnercount:SETFOOTER") })
                                                .setColor(this.client.config.embed.color)

                                            return message.reply({ embeds: [embed] })
                                        }, 100)
                                    }
                                })
                        }, 100)
                    }
                }
            }
```

Error is

```
TypeError: data.matchAll is not a function
    at Function.resolveCode (C:\Users\ALL\Desktop\Slodziak13vNew\node_modules\discord.js\src\util\DataResolver.js:37:17)
    at Function.resolveInviteCode (C:\Users\ALL\Desktop\Slodziak13vNew\node_modules\discord.js\src\util\DataResolver.js:46:17)
    at Slodziak.fetchInvite (C:\Users\ALL\Desktop\Slodziak13vNew\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\Client.js:306:31)
    at Timeout._onTimeout (C:\Users\ALL\Desktop\Slodziak13vNew\events\messageCreate.js:196:21)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:557:17)
    at processTimers (node:internal/timers:500:7)
```

Code is for discord.js 12 (yes, in d.js 12 works but in d.js 13 not)

Btw this is code for count partnerships (same as for example Aiyu or Luminous Nova)

Anyone know how to fix it? or write otherwise so that bot can read the information for invite in message, e.g. guild.id

I tried to replace fetchInvite with fetchInvites or invites.fetch but it didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to check what the value of `inviteLink` is. `fetchInvite()` is expecting it to be some `String`, but it isn't a `String`, causing this error to occur (strings have the method `.matchAll()` on them, so this error is occurring because `inviteLink` is not a string). Log it to the console and see for yourself. It will probably be either `undefined` or an `Array`.

This specific error isn't an issue of djs v12 versus v13. This is an issue with your use of `.match()`. Let's take a look at it:

```js
const inviteLink = await message.content.match(new RegExp(`discord\.(gg|io|me|li)\/.+|discordapp\.com\/invite\.+`))
```

Notice that your regex has a group defined (groups are defined via parentheses, so your first and only group is `(gg|io|me|li)`). When groups are defined in the regex of `String#match()`, it returns an `Array` instead of a single `String`. The returned `Array` goes by this format:

```js
[
    "full match",
    "group 1 match",
    "group 2 match",
    ...
]
```

It does this for however many groups you have defined that are found in the `String`. You only have one group defined, so `inviteLink` will have a length of two. For example, for the invite `discord.gg/abc123` it will look something like this:

```js
[
    "discord.gg/abc123",
    "gg"
]
```

As you can see, what you want is the first item in the `Array` only, since that represents the full invite URL. That's what you need to be passing to `fetchInvite()`, instead of the entire `Array`. You could do this like so:

```js
const inviteLink = message.content.match(/discord\.(gg|io|me|li)\/.+|discordapp\.com\/invite\.+/)?.[0];
```

I used the optional chaining operator here, so it will get the first item in the `Array` as long as the match is not `undefined` (otherwise it will just return `undefined`). Note that I also simplified your regex a little by using regex syntax instead of the `RegExp` object; this could be useful to avoid issues with not double-escaping backslashes.

Comment: As for why the original code in the question works in djs v12 versus djs v13, probably due to differences between how `fetchInvite()` worked or maybe even differences between how nodejs versions worked.

Comment: yes, it work, thank you sooo much, although I struggled for +-5 hours to rewrite the code because something did not work with the plugin, so I wrote my plugin